# How do I use robin-dela/hover-effect library in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module

I want to use this library in a vue component. I installed it via npm & brought it into my main.js file.  When I run this nothing shows up in my-div. Not sure if I am importing wrong? In the docs it states you need tweenMax & three.js as well but those are included in the hover-effect install.

```
   //MAIN.JS file

     `import hoverEffect from 'hover-effect'
      import 'hover-effect/dist/hover-effect.umd.js`


     Vue.config.productionTip = false

      new Vue({
      created(){
      AOS.init({disable: 'mobile'});
      hoverEffect.init({disable: 'mobile'});

     },


    render: h => h(App),
    router,
    }).$mount('#app')

   //COMPONENT FILE
   <div id="my-div"></div>

  </div>

 </template>


   <script>
   import * as hoverEffect from 'hover-effect'

   export default {
    name: 'Quality',
    data() {
   return {
    hoverDistort: null,
    image1: "../assets/award.jpg",
    image2: "../assets/award-2.jpg",
    displacementImage: "../assets/randomImg.jpg"
   }
  },

   methods: { 
      hover: function() {
       this.hoverDistort = new hoverEffect({
       parent: document.getElementById('my-div'),
       intensity: 0.3, 
       image1: this.image1,
       image2: this.image2,
       displacementImage: this.displacementImage
    });

   },

    mounted(){
    this.hover();
```

Comment: Does it output any errors?

Comment: No errors.. I did get a TS one but I made a file with the declaration of the module in it & that error went away

Comment: What you posted here is invalid code (it would error if used in a Vue compoent). If that's because you removed some irrelevant parts, please make sure what's left still parses correctly, without any additional errors you don't actually have in project (due to improper nesting). *Per-se*, I'm noticing `mounted` seems to be inside `methods`, which wouldn't work as component's `mounted` would. Also, you're not closing the component brackets properly. Ideally, you should create a [mcve] (using codesandbox.io or similar).

Answer (score -1):

```
import hoverEffect from 'hover-effect/dist/hover-effect.js'
```

and I changed `e=require("gsap/TweenMax")` to `e=require("gsap")` in the first line
and it worked
the problem was because of the version of gsap installed in modules